# laravel 5.8 and Jquery-ui date format

Tags: jquery-ui, eloquent, jquery-ui-datepicker, laravel-5.8

i use laravel 5.8 and Jquery-ui to get datepicker to select date from input but cant save in database, database format must be in y-M-d but datepicker in m/d/y, so how to edit so can be saved in database ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ If you have written any code that covers the problem of changing date format, please add it to your post. Even if it doesn't do what you want at the moment, it will help other SO contributors to help you

Comment: Just change your date format before updating/inserting to your table.
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->date));